# ¿Cuál es el origen de la segunda acepción de enajenar?

Tags: significado, historia

El DLE recoge 5 significados para el verbo 'enajenar', y (en lo personal, no lo puedo asegurar por norma...) lo habitual es asociarlo con el segundo significado:

> Sacar a alguien fuera de sí, entorpecerle o turbarle el uso de la razón o de los sentidos

Sin embargo, al revisar el CORDE, en los escritos del siglo XIV prevalece la primera acepción:

> Vender o ceder la propiedad de algo u otros derechos.

Y el mapa de diccionarios de la RAE muestra todas las acepciones en sus versiones. ¿De dónde surge esta segunda acepción que parece haber ganado mayor uso actualmente?

Comment: Tal vez haya variaciones regionales en cuanto al uso de la palabra (y tal vez de allí venga ese segundo uso de la palabra), pero al menos en México, se suele entender como "vender o ceder propiedad" (cosa que puedes confirmar dando una vista a la entrada de enajenar en el Diccionario del Español de México).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sospecho que viene del concepto jurídico de [enajenación mental](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EulzqeC#6TuGu7W), que se aplica cuando una persona se considera que ha perdido el control de sus pensamientos y actos, y por tanto no es responsable de los mismos.
Este uso cae dentro de la primera acepción, pues se considera que la capacidad de juicio y raciocinio de dicha persona ha sido enajenada, es decir, que ya no la posee.

Seguramente a base de oír esta expresión en telediarios y noticieros, es como se ha establecido el uso de "enajenar" como "producir enajenación mental", es decir, llevar a alguien a un punto de ira o locura en el cual pierde la razón.